# Karate API framework - Validate randomly displayed items in response

Tags: karate

I am using Karate API framework for the API automation and came across with one scenario, the scenario is when I am hitting a post call it gives me some json response and few of the items are having tags whereas few of them are showing tags as blank to get all the tags below is the feature file scenario line

```
* def getTags = get response.items[*].resource.tags
```

It is giving me response as

```
[
[
],
[
],
[
  { 
   "tags" : "Entertainment" 
  } 
],
[
],
[
  { 
   "tags" : "Family" 
  } 
],
```

As you can see out of 5 or 6 tags only 2 tags are having the value, so I want to capture if any tags value is showing or not. What would be the logic for the assertion considering these tags can all come as empty and sometimes with come with a string value. In above case "Family" & "Entertainment"

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a second variable to strip out the empties, or maybe your original JsonPath should use `..`, you can experiment:

```
* def allowed = ['Music', 'Entertainment', 'Documentaries', 'Family']
* def response =
"""
[
   [

   ],
   [

   ],
   [
      {
         "tags":"Entertainment"
      }
   ],
   [

   ],
   [
      {
         "tags":"Family"
      }
   ]
]
"""
* def temp = get response..tags
* print temp
* match each temp == "#? allowed.contains(_)"
```

Comment: Let me check that once and I will get back.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion but these values are not hard coded these are dynamic and if it says entertainment then there are chances that next time it would show something else.

Comment: Can you please edit your response as per my recent response, this will be helpful for others too.

Comment: Currently the code you shared in your response 
* match each temp == "#? _ == 'Entertainment' || _ == 'Family'"
this will match for just entertainment and family however these tags are in dynamic nature and these values will get changed down the time. Hence I asked for the long term solution.

Hope the problem statement is clear now.

Comment: So are you saying this line * match each temp == "#? _ == 'Entertainment' || _ == 'Family'" would work for all ??

Comment: @vdrulerz it is ok, just forget everything I said, you don't get it. edited my answer

Answer (score 3):

```
* match each response.items[*].resource.tags == "##string"
```

This will validate that tags either doesn't exist or is a string.

Comment: Let me check that once and I will get back.

Comment: No problem. I wasn't sure from your question if you wanted to check specified values for `tags` or just if it was a string when present. When you have an enum of allowed values, it's of course best to check it like Peter suggested.